# HTA - Object Requied Windows 8.1

Tags: vb.net, windows, vbscript, hta

I created a small HTA to assist in imaging new machines. The HTA copies a users data from their user folders, firefox and chrome profiles to the new machine. The script connects to a remote computer via UNC checks for the username given, specific folders and if they exist it will copy the files to the new machine.

If I run the script and set the destination folder to something generic like 'c:\temp' it works fine, no errors. However, when I set the destination folder to the correct path as seen in the script I get the following error. I do not see the problem. Can someone help?

---

> Line: 249
>
> Char: 38
>
> Error: Object required: 'dFolder'
>
> Code: 0 URL:
>
> file:///CopyData.hta

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">

<!--
'#==============================================================================
'#==============================================================================
'#  SCRIPT.........:    CopyData.hta
'#  AUTHOR.........:    brandon h.
'#  VERSION........:
'#  DATE...........:
'#  LICENSE........:
'#  COMMENT........:    Copy user data from remote device to local device.
'#                      Run script on destination device.
'#==============================================================================
'#==============================================================================
-->

<html>
<hta:application
    applicationname="CopyData"     
    border="thin"
    borderstyle="normal"
    innerborder="no"
    caption="yes"
    contextmenu="no"
    icon=""
    maximizebutton="no"
    minimizebutton="no"
    navigable="no"
    scroll="no"
    scrollflat="no"
    selection="no"
    showintaskbar="yes"
    singleinstance="yes"
    sysmenu="yes"
    windowstate="normal"
>

<head>
<title>Copy User Data</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function loadHTA() {
    // window size
    var resW=screen.availWidth
    var resH=screen.availHeight

    if (resW >= 800) {
        myW=resW/4
        myH=resH/4
        self.focus()
        self.moveTo(eval(resW/2-myW/2), eval(resH/2-myH/2))
        self.resizeTo(300, 250)
    } else {
        self.focus()
    }
}
</script>

<script language="vbscript">
    Option Explicit

    ' Define global variables
    Const FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG = &H10&
    Dim userName, wShell, oFSO, oShell, strIP
    Dim strComputer, strUserName, objWMIService
    Dim sourceFolder, destFolder, dest, dFolder

    ' Create global objects
    Set wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    '**** Used javascript instead - see loadHTA function ****
    ' Set window location and size
    'Sub Window_onLoad
    '       window.resizeTo 200,200
    '       window.moveTo (screen.width - 600)/2, (screen.height - 200)/2
    'End Sub 

    ' Check if folders exist on remote device
    Function CopyData()

        ' Create function related objects
        Set wShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        ' Define function related variables
        strUserName = document.all.item("userName").value
        strIP = document.all.item("ip").value

        ' Check for root user folder
        If NOT oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName) Then
            wShell.popup "User: " & strUserName & " does not exist.",,"Error", 48
            'window.close()
        Else

            ' Contacts
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\contacts") Then
                'wShell.popup "contacts",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\contacts"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\.contacts"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Desktop
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\desktop") Then
                'wShell.popup "desktop",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\desktop"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\desktop"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Downloads
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\downloads") Then
                'wShell.popup "downloads",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\downloads"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\downloads"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Favorites
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\favorites") Then
                'wShell.popup "favorites",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\favorites"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\favorites"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Links
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\links") Then
                'wShell.popup "links",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\links"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\links"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Documents
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\documents") Then
                'wShell.popup "documents",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\documents"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\documents"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' NoMachine
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\.nx") Then
                'wShell.popup "nx",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\.nx"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\.nx"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If
            
            ' SSH
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\.ssh") Then
                'wShell.popup "ssh",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\.ssh"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\.ssh"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' PST/OST
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook") Then
                'wShell.popup "outlook",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook"
                'destFolder = "c:\users" & strUserName & "\appdata\local\microsoft\outlook"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Signatures
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\microsoft\signatures") Then
                'wShell.popup "signatures",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\microsoft\signatures"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\microsoft\signatures"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Office Templates
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\microsoft\templates") Then
                'wShell.popup "templates",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\microsoft\templates"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\microsoft\templates"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Firefox
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\mozilla\firefox\profiles") Then
                'wShell.popup "profiles",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\mozilla\firefox\profiles"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\roaming\mozilla\firefox\profiles"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

            ' Chrome
            If oFSO.FolderExists("\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default") Then
                'wShell.popup "profiles",,"Error", 48
                'destFolder = "\\booger\home\bhoneycutt\tmp"
                sourceFolder = "\\" & strIP & "\c$\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default"
                destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\appdata\local\google\chrome\user data\default"
                CopyRemote sourceFolder, destFolder
            End If

        End If
    End Function

    ' Copy data from remote device to local
    Sub CopyRemote(sourceFolder, destFolder)
        'wShell.popup "Now copying " & sourceFolder & " to " & destFolder,,"blah", 48
        Set dFolder = oShell.NameSpace(destFolder)
        dFolder.CopyHere sourceFolder, FOF_CREATEPROGRESSDLG
    End Sub

    ' Clean up
    Set wShell = Nothing
    Set oFSO = Nothing
</script>
</head>

<body onload="loadHTA()" bgcolor="#5174bc">
    <table border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <div id="results"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <input type="textbox" name="userName"></input><br>
                <font size="-1"><b style="color: #fff">username</b></font><br>
                <input type="textbox" name="ip"></input><br>
                <font size="-1"><b style="color: #fff">ip address</b></font><br>
                &nbsp;<br>
                <button name="CopyData" onclick="CopyData()" accesskey="H" style="background-color: #d1dbe9; border:1px solid black;">
                    <b><u>C</u>opyData</b>
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: On what I see as line 107, is your `destFolder` variable supposed to begin with ".contacts"?  `destFolder = "c:\users\" & strUserName & "\.contacts"`

Comment: 1) the outlook case does not define a destination folder 2) I think you should check that the destination folder exists before trying to copy anything to it

Comment: LOL. I really hope that is it. I can't believe I overlooked that. Ahh! Thanks guys.